# Tridion Configuration Issue (Works locally but not remotely)

Tags: core-service, iis-and-asp.net

We have been having a strange issue with core services. Our application uses Angular as the front end and ASP.NET for back end. The back end api service connects to Tridion using core services. The Application and Tridion core services are running in different servers.

The issue we are having is that the application when accessed locally on the servers works fine. But accessing the application remotely throws an error. This error is thrown when client.Impersonate("Windows Account") is called. The "Windows Account" is present in Tridion Users. But the same code works well when running the application locally on the server.

The application uses ApplicationPoolIdentity for Identity and uses Windows authentication.

There only time the application works remotely is when we configure Tridion Impersonation Account in Identity. 

If I remove the account it does not work.

Did anyone else have this issue? Any insight to this issue is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I'm almost afraid to ask... but this is not a front-end/web-facing web application we're talking about, right? It's for internal editors only, right?

Comment: @NunoLinhares .. yes you are correct. It is an intranet application. Not a public facing web application.

Comment: Try configuring the machine account (`<domain>\<hostname>$`) as Tridion Impersonation User.  In general, Application Pool Identities are represented as the machine account for accessed to network resources. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities#accessing-the-network

Comment: @S P thanks. We’ve seen a case recently where a website was calling the coreservice, I guess I’m still traumatized. Rick’s answer is the right one.

Comment: @Nuno, headless CMS done wrong? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring the machine account (`<domain>\<hostname>$`) of the web app server as Tridion Impersonation User.

In general, Application Pool Identities are represented as the machine account for access to network resources. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities#accessing-the-network

Comment: thank you for your reply. The IT team is requesting not to use Tridion Impersonation User. The application is working fine when run locally on the server itself with out Tridion Impersonation Account setup. The problem is when accessing the web application from any other machine.